# Could someone explain this statement about logic?

Tags: logic, axioms, incompleteness

I'm literally new to logic, yet, I'm interested in Godel's Incompleteness Theorem. Reading a "pdf proof" in the internet, I encounter the following sentence:

"We assume a theory of arithmetic, say
$N
= (
ℕ
,
+
,
×
)$ to be consistent"

I tried to research this and if I understood correctly, a consistent theory is one that doesn't lead to contradictions...right?

However, I couldn't get to find the meaning of "$N
= (
ℕ
,
+
,
×
)$" and I was wondering if someone could explain it assuming that I know nothing more than high school math.

---

I would truly appreciate any help/thoughts!

Comment: I think that sentence is sloppily written. I imagine the intention was to say that such a set *exists* and satisfies the usual axioms of arithmetic.

Comment: However, even saying that is far from clear. What does it mean that the set exists? (The point is that this is the *standard* structure of arithmetic. But mentioning it is really just confusing.) Plus, what is the intended theory ("the usual axioms" I refer to)? It could simply be the "true" theory (all statements true of the natural numbers), or first-order Peano arithmetic, or second-order Peano arithmetic. In the context of incompleteness the difference matters.

Comment: (It would help to see whether context clarifies the author's intention if you provide a link. But really, my advice is to read a different source.)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo. The set you talk about is the Natural numbers, right? I have heard of Peano axioms, I don't know if that is what you are referring by "Piano arithmetic", I'm going to try and research that part myself.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo. The author doesn't seem to give much content: https://mat.iitm.ac.in/home/asingh/public_html/papers/goedel.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link. A quick glance confirmed my suspicions: There are too many technical mistakes in that write up (a model is different from its theory. It satisfies statements rather than prove them, etc). Reading that pdf will be confusing and misleading.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo. I'll try to find something else then. Might be a good idea to ask here for a better pdf. Thanks, really.

Comment: Not a pdf, but a nice not too technical account can be found in **The incompleteness phenomenon** by Goldstern and Judah.

Comment: Good luck. This is a very pretty area and incompleteness is a fascinating topic. Hope you enjoy it.

Answer (score 1):

A theory $T$ is typically a set of statements that is *logically closed*, meaning that all statements that are logical consequences of $T$ are already included in $T$. If the contradiction is not in $T$, then $T$ is said to be consistent.

Now, for it to be a theory of arithmetic, we want the statements in the set to use a language that includes arithmetical symbols like $0$, $+$, and $\times$.

So, I suppose you could refer to a theory using such symbols as $T=(0,+,\times)$. This would not tell us exactly what statements are in $T$ though, merely what symbols it is using.

The author denoting a theory as $N = (\mathbb{N}, + , \times)$ is really strange: $\mathbb{N}$ is most likely not a symbol that the author wants to use as part of the *language* to express statements about arithmetic, but is instead the intended domain. In fact, $\mathbb{N}$ is the domain of what is typically called the 'standard interpretation' or 'standard structure' of arithmetic, and this interpretation maps the symbol $+$ to the arithmetical operation of addition, $\times$ to multiplication, and the symbol $0$ to the number $0$.

In fact, I wonder if that is what the author tried to denote by $N$: not a theory, but the standard interpretation ...