# Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems proof

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I am trying to understand the proof of Gödel's incompleteness theorems. I am using this document https://mat.iitm.ac.in/home/asingh/public_html/papers/goedel.pdf
and finding it quite helpful, but I am a little confused about a particular part of it - on page 2, what is meant by "extend $g$ to proofs of formulas..."? What are $X_1$, $X_2$, etc.?

Comment: Someone had asked about that same paper before. My advice is that you do not read it and instead look for a different source. The paper has many mistakes and serious technical inaccuracies. I doubt it will end up being helpful, in spite of your current opinion.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2404682/462).

Comment: To echo Andres' comments, I **strongly** recommend another source. For example, another paper by the same author contains this: $${}{}$$ "We look at the phrase “the ball game definitely ends in $k$ or fewer moves” as a property of the natural number k. Call this property as $P(k)$. Then “the ball game eventually ends” is translated as $\exists k P(k)$." $${}{}$$ This is, of course, absolutely bonkers: it's like claiming (in fact, it *is* claiming) "every natural number is finite, so there is a largest natural number." And from the rest of the paper this isn't a typo but rather a genuine error!

Comment: To clarify: that other paper is also about incompleteness, so I'm not randomly picking on an unrelated mistake. The paper is [this one](https://home.iitm.ac.in/asingh/papers/ballgame.pdf). (The specific focus of that paper, incidentally, is an interesting one: the author is trying to give an exposition of an argument of Smullyan's, which is itself a variant of [Kirby/Paris' result on Goodstein sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodstein%27s_theorem) intended to be easier to approach.)

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is a *formula*, i.e. a string of symbols.

The function $g$ has been defined for "basic" symbols: $g(\top)=1, g(\bot)=2, \ldots$

Then it is extended to formulas in this way; for $X= \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \ldots \sigma_m$:

> $g(X)=g(σ_1 σ_2 \ldots σ_m) = 2^{g(σ_1)} \times 3^ {g(σ_2)} \times \ldots \times p_m ^{g(σ_m)}$.

A *proof*, i.e. a *derivation* in the calculus, is a sequence of formulas: $X_1, X_2, \ldots X_n$.

Thus, $g$ can be extended again to encode proofs by:

> $g(X_1 X_2 \ldots X_n) = 2^{g(X_1)} \times 3^{g(X_2)} \times \ldots \times p_n ^{g(X_m)}$.